# Windows 10 cannot access certain websites after hibernating

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns

After hibernating, then re-powering on my computer, sometimes a certain website will not work. Very often, this is a website or service that I was using actively before I shutdown the computer (for example, chess.com was open in my browser, or I was using discord to chat.

---

My router has no trouble at all with `ping`, `curl` or `nslookup` to the website (e.g: `chess.com`, or `discord.com`). These are big websites, and they are not "down". Likewise, my phone and laptop all access these sites fine.

Output from my router, as proof that it works:

```
# nslookup discord.com 8.8.8.8
Name:      discord.com
Address 1: 162.159.128.233
Address 2: 162.159.136.232
Address 3: 162.159.137.232
Address 4: 162.159.138.232
Address 5: 162.159.135.232
```

Rebooting my computer fixes the issue. It does not seem to go away if I just wait.

All my DNS records, on Windows and my router, are always set up to `8.8.8.8`. I do not use anything else.

I have tried `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`. These do nothing. Unplugging the network cable, and disabling the network interface also do nothing.

I have taken a good look at `hosts`. There is nothing suspicious there. And besides, this happens with different sites every time.

Here is an example of a failed DNS lookup while the issue is happening. Note that this ONLY happens for this ONE website.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup discord.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** dns.google can't find discord.com: Non-existent domain
```

Windows Subsystem for Linux seems to use windows as its DNS resolver, so it has the same issues. Interestingly, even if I force it to use 8.8.8.8, it has the same issue. I assume this is because it's hitting the same issue as Windows is.

```
addisong@addison-windows:~$ nslookup discord.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find discord.com: NXDOMAIN
```

To showcase the **most ridiculous behaviour**, I can curl `www.discord.com` (with `www` before it), and it works, but `discord.com` does not:

```
addisong@addison-windows:~$ curl -v https://www.discord.com
...
* Connected to www.discord.com (162.159.128.233) port 443 (#0)
...
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.discord.com
...
< HTTP/2 301
< date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 07:16:32 GMT
< location: https://discord.com/
```

And discord.com (without www):

```
addisong@addison-windows:~$ curl -v https://discord.com
* Could not resolve host: discord.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: discord.com
```

I can definitely send traffic to the IP - it seems to surely be a problem with the DNS.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I don't know much, but I would suggest looking at WireShark captures, and look for DNS messages related to affected sites.

Comment: 1)  have you tried a different browser?  2) Is it always the same sites that stop working ?

Comment: Browser does not affect it. It has happened three times - twice with chess.com, and once with discord.com